# Spring MVC Issue

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I have a web-app that has some heavy controller logic inside controllers. However I would like to use web-flows on top of this. From what I learn by reading online, spring web flow totally circumvents controllers in a sense that its different states assume controller functionality.

Is it practical to put web flow on top of mvc when I have some really heavy controllers with heavy logic inside it?

I would not like to put such heavy logic inside those flow **state-transition-data** definitions xmls using spEL. It is ugly and instead they rightly belong to the domain of java space inside controllers.

Answer (score 0):

The spring MVC controllers don't match well with Spring webflow, as Spring Webflow provides a stateful controller built based on the flow definition xml.

But if the logic to determine the next view is not well expressed otherwise, you can make all view states transition to an action state, where you determine via Java code what is the next view:

```
<action-state id="decideNextView">
    <evaluate expression="someBeans.determineNextView()" />
    <transition on="begin" to="beginState" />
    <transition on="end" to="endState" />
    <transition on="other" to="someOtherState" />
</action-state>
```

This way the view transition logic is not on the XML but in Java code.

Comment: I agree with what you said about webflow not getting along well with mvc. But for some reason (may be marketing strategy) spring claims that webflow is supposed to work on top of mvc which is a big deviation from truth.

Comment: They hardly fit together. They are fundamentally different approaches. Thankfully some books do a better job of highlighting this point.

Comment: About transitioning to action state - nah, that blows the whole thing out of proportion. I dont want the app to become unwieldy and complex. All these frameworks are supposed to make the back end look tidy and neat. I am more inclined to drop web flow at the moment.